# How to restrict ListContourPlot with two criteria?

Tags: plotting

I use `ListContourPlot` to show exclusions in a physical parameter space. I have restrictions like `A < 5` and `B > 120`. I also have data lists in the form of `{{Input1, Input2, A, B, C, ...}, {Input,....}}`. I create lists of triplets with the inputs as x and y coordinates and the interesting quantity as a third: `AList = {{Input1, Input2, A}, {Input1, Input2, A}, ...}`. Then I simply use `ListContourPlot[AList, Contours -> {5}, ContourShading -> {None, Red}]` to create a red shape that covers the excluded area. I do this e.g. in red and blue for A and B respectively. Then I use `Show[LCP1, LCP2, ...]` to overlay them into a single plot.

Now, it would be nice to also show the area that is excluded by A and B in a third color. Is there a possibility to create contours based on two criteria?

I manged to get what I want, by creating a list of elements that fulfill criterion A and then plot the exclusion for B the same way as above then doing it once over with a list of elements that fulfill criterion B and plot the exclusion for A. This is cumbersome, however, so I wonder whether it is possible to do it in one step.

Comment: `AList = {{Input1, Input2, A}, {Input1, Input2, A}, ...}` doesn't reveal your intentions, I think

Comment: I think I didn't really understand your question. Could you provide some minimal concrete data sample and code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could interpolate your data and use `RegionPlot`:

```
(* example data *)
alist = Table[{x, y, (x + 2)^2 + y^2}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}, {y, -5, 5, 0.1}]~Flatten~1;
blist = Table[{x, y, 15 (x - 2)^2 + 10 y^2}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}, {y, -5, 5, 0.1}]~Flatten~1;

(* interpolation *)
afunc = Interpolation[alist];
bfunc = Interpolation[blist];

(* plotting *)
With[{a = afunc[x, y] < 5, b = bfunc[x, y] > 120}, 
 RegionPlot[{a, b, a && b}, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green, Blue}]]
```

[image]